# Wake up and record in Windows Media Center on a Mac Mini

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, windows-media-center, mac-mini, htpc

I'm currently considering buying a Mac Mini to use as a media center.
I plan to install Windows 7 (or 8) on it, using Boot Camp.

Will it be able to go into standby or hibernate (S3, S4?) and wake up to record TV scheduled in Windows Media Center?

I haven't been able to find concrete information on supported standby types when running Windows under boot camp, and if Windows will even be able to wake when a recording should start. 
I just want to be clear on any limitations in this area before I buy anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the opportunity to borrow a 2011 Mac Mini, so I'm able to answer my own question:

The Mini will wake in time for a scheduled recording, both from sleep and hibernation.

I tested using Windows 7, since Boot Camp support for Windows 8 is not officially available at this time.